# I want to insert null in database if i dont choose an image from imageupload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a `FileUpload` control and when I don't insert an image, I want to insert `DBNull` into the database. So far I have only errors with `DBNull.Value`. The table allow null for column `ImageData`.

Here is the code:

```
protected void button_sign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
    {
        string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userimage/" + str));
        string Image = "~/userimage/" + str.ToString();
        string name = username_textbox.Text;
        string email = email_textbox.Text;
        string pass = password_textbox.Text;

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Register values(@Username, @Email, @Password, @ImageData)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", Image);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            lblMsg.Text = "Înregistrare cu succes";
            Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=login.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         lblMsg.Text = "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your register table allow NULL on the ImageData column? If it does, then you should be able to set it to null and the insert should be okay.  What error do you get?

Comment: Yes i put null,   [ImageData] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Slight detour...You really should not be storing passwords as clear text. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: in that else i want to put DBNull but i cant. I cant use Image the parameter... i dont know how to add the DBNull.value....if i use Image=DBNull.Value it said Image is an ambiguos reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the value of `Image` at the beginning the rest of the code could stay generic.

```
protected void button_sign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object Image;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile==true)
    {
        string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userimage/" + str));
        Image = "~/userimage/" + str.ToString();
    }
    else {
        Image = System.DBNull.Value;
    }

    string name = username_textbox.Text;
    string email = email_textbox.Text;
    string pass = password_textbox.Text;

    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Register values(@Username,@Email,@Password,@ImageData)", con))
    {
        // pick the appropriate SqlDbType type for each parameter
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar){Value = name});
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar){Value = email});
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar){Value = pass});
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", SqlDbType.VarChar){Value = Image});

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblMsg.Text = "Înregistrare cu succes";
        Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=login.aspx");
    }
```

Some other notes though

- You should specify the Database types using the [SqlDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) in your parameters to make sure that the values are translated correctly by the ado.net code.
- Wrap you Command in a using block as well
- No need to close the connection, the `using` block will handle that for you.
- Do not store passwords in clear text. Instead store a salted hash of the password.

Comment: There is no need to wrap SqlCommand in using block. This will bring nothing.

Comment: @SereDaniel - glad to hear it. I updated my example with a better use of SqlDbType, you just have to specify the correct type for each parameter unless they are all varchar in which case you can leave it as is.

Comment: thank you i will study what you  said and posted, thank again for your time

Comment: @mybirthname - there is not a need but it is good practice. If a type implements IDIsposable it is better to get in the practice of wrapping it. To counter that point there is also no detriment to doing it.

Comment: @IGor if it is for the sake of learning I agree, if he doesn't know that all IDisposable should be disposed.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", FileUpload1.HasFile ? Image: DbNull.Value);
```

Also refactor your code a little bit:

```
string image = "";
if (FileUpload1.HasFile==true)
{
    string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/userimage/" + str));
    image  = "~/userimage/" + str.ToString();
}

string name = username_textbox.Text;
string email = email_textbox.Text;
string pass = password_textbox.Text;

String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Register values(@Username,@Email,@Password,@ImageData)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", FileUpload1.HasFile ? image: DbNull.Value);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
}

lblMsg.Text = "Înregistrare cu succes";
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL=login.aspx");
```

Don't start your variables with `UpperCase` letters.